# Compare values of different time-stamps and identify if they have changed

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, min

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=02a72c37ca816df230b5861457bf8180)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    plan_week VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, plan_week 
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "CW01"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "CW01"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "CW01"),

("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "CW01"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_B", "CW02"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "CW02"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_D", "CW01");
```

**Expected Result**

```
product          week_switch
Product_A           no
Product_B           yes
Product_C           yes
Product_D           no
```

---

In the above result I want to check if a `plan_week` of a product has switched from one `time_stamp` to antoher `time_stamp`. 
If the condition is met `yes` should be used as value. If not `no` should be inserted.

```
SELECT
product
FROM operations 
GROUP BY 1;
```

I have no clue what kind of query I need to achieve this.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
select
    product,
    case when min(plan_week) <> max(plan_week) then 'yes' else 'no' end as week_switch
from operations
where time_stamp in ('2020-01-01', '2020-03-15')
group by product
```

This aggregates the rows by product. Then, the `case` expression checks if there are (at least) two different values in `plan_week`, and sets the flag accordingly.

The `where` clause is not strictly necessary. You can remove it, depending on whether you want to check two particular dates or the entire dataset.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=548d6e2ef0f148127378c64ffa7cfaae

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just aggregation with a `case` expression:

```
select product,
       (case when min(plan_week) = max(plan_week) then 'no' else 'yes' end) as flag
from operations o
group by product;
```